# How can I extract elements and value from series of strings and arrange it rightly?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame like this,

```
DF1= c(
  "Name : John Miller, Math : 100, History : 80, Physics: 90",
  "Name : Mary Smith, French ： 99, History : 90, Physics: 89",
  "Name : Eddy Abbot, Math : 90, French : 85, Chemistry : 90"
)
```

Would like to make it a data.table in this way (better in data.table format)

```
          Name   Math   French History   Physics    Chemistry
1: John Miller    100       NA      80        90           NA
2:  Mary Smith     NA       99      90        89           NA
3:  Eddy Abbot     90       85      NA        NA           90
```

Wondering if my idea is at the right direction:

1. Split the strings into words based on ",".
2. Get the keywords, "French, "Math", etc, based on " : ".
3. Fill in the right row and right col with the value respectively. and done.

Would like to invite advice on step 3 and many thanks.

Comment: For clarity, what you *want* is a `data.frame` (or frame-like) object. What you *have* is a `character` vector of length 3, with perhaps a straight-forward structure for programmatically extracting your structure. Just words, perhaps, but in a different question it might cause some confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace each comma and end-of-line with a newline and each space-colon with just colon.  Read that using `readLines` to break up the strings into separate lines and use `trimws` to remove any junk whitespace.  At this point the file is in Debian Control Format (DCF) so we can use `read.dcf` to read it creating character matrix `m`.  Now convert `m` to data.table and convert the types.

```
dcf <- trimws(readLines(textConnection(gsub(" :", ":", gsub(",|$", "\n", DF1)))))
m <- read.dcf(textConnection(dcf))
DT <- as.data.table(m)[, lapply(.SD, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)]
```

giving:

```
> DT
          Name Math History Physics French Chemistry
1: John Miller  100      80      90     NA        NA
2:  Mary Smith   NA      90      89     99        NA
3:  Eddy Abbot   90      NA      NA     85        90
```

### Note

We used the object name `DF1` for consistency with the question but it is a character vector, not a data frame, so you might want to choose a different name for it.

Comment: the key is `textConnection` and `readLines`. Read each string as a line, and make it an acceptable format for `textConnection` with little trim work, then let it work. Got it! Thanks!

Comment: Now I see the trick (one of). The `\n` at the end of line is necessary for squaring the data. if simply `strsplit(DF1, " , ") %>% unlist`, the geometry will be ruined and make it much more complicated. **THANKS!**

Comment: I just noticed that the original dataset is squared in the beginning. All three has 4 elements. What if some of them has more? Then it is not symmetrical at all. How would you suggest in such case? @G. Grothendieck?

Comment: DCF requires that there be a blank line between successive records and that is the purpose of the \n at the end of each input line.  The code does not depend on there being the same number of specified fields on each line.  Try removing a few fields from the example data to make it irregular and it still works.  See `?read.dcf` for a description of DCF format.

Comment: I am trying to understand the effect of `textConnection` , `read.dcf`. These are 2 new things just met. **Thanks** for the explanation, sir.

Comment: `read.dcf` takes a file name or a connection as input but we want to give it a character vector.  `textConnection(x)` turns the character vector `x` into a connection acceptable to `read.dcf`.

Comment: Thanks for the great advice. It works and I have learned. **Thanks**

Answer (score 2):

We convert it to a `tibble`,create a row names column ('rn'), expand the rows by splitting at `,` (`separate_rows`), `separate` the 'col' at `:` into 'col1' and 'col2', `spread` it to 'wide' format, and change the type

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(col = DF1) %>%
   rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
   separate_rows(col, sep = "\\s*,\\s*")  %>% 
   separate(col, into = c('col1', 'col2'), sep="\\s*:\\s*") %>% 
   spread(col1, col2) %>%
   select(-rn) %>% 
   mutate_all(type.convert, as.is = TRUE) %>%
   select(Name, Math, French, History, Physics, Chemistry)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#   Name         Math French History Physics Chemistry
#    <chr>       <int>  <int>   <int>   <int>     <int>
#1 John Miller   100     NA      80      90        NA
#2 Mary Smith     NA     99      90      89        NA
#3 Eddy Abbot     90     85      NA      NA        90
```

---

It is also possible to convert to `JSON` format and then use `fromJSON`

```
library(jsonlite)
out <-  fromJSON(paste0("[", paste("{", gsub('"(\\d+)"', "\\1", 
   gsub('(\\w+)\\s*:\\s*([^,]+)', '"\\1":"\\2"', DF1)), "}", sep="", collapse=",\n"), "]"))

out
#         Name Math History Physics French Chemistry
#1 John Miller  100      80      90     NA        NA
#2  Mary Smith   NA      90      89     99        NA
#3  Eddy Abbot   90      NA      NA     85        90
```

Comment: Yes! I can make it a long table then reshape it! Will try now! Thanks @akrun

Comment: Tip from G. Grothendieck is workable for the data I gave. but, my case data is not thorough enough. What if it is not square at the beginning, the long table approach would be more applicable. Thanks, @akrun.

Comment: **Thanks** but now I am out bcs of the regex. Any suggestion on reading material?

Comment: @Grec001  You can check [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for learning the regex.  In this case, it is an easy one.  We capture the word (`(\\w+)`) followed by zero or more space (`\\s*`) followed by a colon `:`, then again space and characters that are not a comma in the second capture group, and replace it with the backrefence in quotes(`"\\1"`).  The second gsub is for removing the quotes from the numeric values and then do `paste` to get the JSON format

Comment: Thanks Akrun, it helps!